# Sendgrid - Trigger email via webhook from non-zapier

Tags: email, webhooks, sendgrid

I've done quite a bit of research but can't seem to find an answer on this. Sendgrid has great documentation on event webhooks that send information after an email send, but very little on inbound webhooks that point towards sendgrid to send an email.

[This is the only article I could find - but it's uniquely centered around Zapier which I'd rather not use.](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/zapier-sending-for-new-webhook-data)

Does anyone have any resources on how I could use webhooks that point towards Sendgrid to trigger emails without using Zapier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you want to trigger something on a third party service like SendGrid, it is described as an API request rather than as a webhook. To send an email using SendGrid you need to make an API request to the SendGrid API.

I see your username is Python Learner, here is a tutorial for [how to send an email with Python using the SendGrid API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-python).

The resultant code from the tutorial looks like this, but I recommend you take a look through the whole tutorial as there is lots to learn:

```py
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, To, Content

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("test@example.com")  # Change to your verified sender
to_email = To("test@example.com")  # Change to your recipient
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)

# Get a JSON-ready representation of the Mail object
mail_json = mail.get()

# Send an HTTP POST request to /mail/send
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_json)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
```

Comment: Hello @philnash - ahh my name is a bit outdated. I'm currently trying to build a website with a membership model using Memberstack https://www.memberstack.com/

The goal is to trigger a welcome email after someone signs up. I believe they trigger this transactional event with a webhook, and all of their APIs are not event based. How would I integrate this? I fully understand the tutorial, but I don't quite know how to make it 'event based' as opposed to 'time based' on some schedule. I'm using Javascript in this case!

Comment: Ah, I see. So in this case Memberstack will send a webhook when your user signs up. You need an application that can receive that webhook (HTTP request) and then run the code that will send the email. If you’re using JavaScript, then you would need a web server, like Express, to receive these incoming HTTP requests. Or you could implement it as a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions). Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes! I use netlify and I think they have serverless functions as well, so I will try that out. Thank you for clarifying. I was extremely confused because I assumed there was some way for the webhook to point to sendgrid as an endpoint and couldn't figure it out

Comment: Ah yeah, Netlify does have Functions and they can do the same. You don't really want to be able to point any webhook at a URL and have it send emails on your behalf, there likely needs to be some authentication and some customisation involved. That's the sort of thing you can do in your Netlify function, translating the information from the Memberstack webhook into the email that you want to send. Hope it goes well for you.